# Why doesn't getColumnType work for number type?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I want to get the types of my columns in java.
I do it that way:

```
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int type = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        type = rsmd.getColumnType(i);

        if (type == Types.VARCHAR) {
            System.out.println("str");
        } else if (type == Types.INTEGER){
            System.out.println("int");
        }

    }
```

This code works for Strings but it doesn't work for the `number` type in sql.
Also in [the list of types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html) there isn't a number type? 
How can I fix that problem?

> EDIT

`Types.NUMERIC` is the right answer

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, [`Types.NUMERIC`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html#NUMERIC) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Which DBMS and JDBC driver are you using? And what is the type definition in the database?

Comment: `Types.NUMERIC` doesn't just work in the if condition but is the right answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ResultSetMetaData column indexes are 1-based, not 0-based, Use a switch statement. The JDBC type returned for a column declared as INTEGER in SQL may vary depending on your RDBMS.

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int type = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    type = rsmd.getColumnType(i);
    switch (type) {
        case Types.SMALLINT:
            break;
        case Types.INTEGER:
            break;
        case Types.BIGINT:
            break;
        case Types.DECIMAL:
            break;
        case Types.NUMERIC:
            break;
        case Types.FLOAT:
            break;
        case Types.DOUBLE:
            break;
        default:
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works! Do you have an idea why `Types.NUMERIC` doesn't work in the if condition but it in the switch it does?

Comment: Most databases will inform DECIMAL for a SQL DECIMAL and and INTEGER, SMALLINT or BIGINT for such SQL types. But Oracle will inform NUMERIC for columns defined NUMBER, INTEGER, SMALLINT or BIGINT. Maybe that is the issue.